# Fatal Error when installing woocommerce despite upgrading

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to install woocommerce on my website and have selected a new theme to do so. I even upgraded from an old server to a new one running the latest version of php.

However, I still get the same fatal crash every time I activate the woocommerce plugin:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to
>   allocate 64000 bytes) in home/******/*****/*****/settings.php on line
>   889

Is this something to do with my server settings? Can it be fixed without upgrading to yet another hosting package?

Answer (score 3):

Your WP install is attempting to exceed the [PHP memory](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) allocated to it. This limit may be defined by WordPress, your server configuration files such as `.htaccess` or `php.ini`, or your host.

WooCommerce has a [doc explaining a few ways to increase it](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/increasing-the-wordpress-memory-limit/). They seem to recommend `256 MB`.

WordPress [does as well](https://wordpress.org/support/article/editing-wp-config-php/#increasing-memory-allocated-to-php) with some more details.

There are a few things you can try.

**In WordPress:**

Try adding the following to your `wp-config.php` file right above the line that says, “Happy Blogging”:

`define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );`

**In the php.ini:**

If that does not work and you have access to your `php.ini` you edit the line that starts with `memory_limit` to look like the following:

`memory_limit = 256M ;`

**In your .htaccess file:**

The `.htaccess` can be found in the same directory as your `wp-config.php` file. Add the following on a new line:

`php_value memory_limit 256M`

**Contact your host**

If these do not work you'll need to contact your host to ask about the limits.