# What's the difference between WP_MEMORY_LIMIT and WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT?

Tags: wp-config, memory

What's the difference beetween

`define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '96M' );`
and 
`define( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );`

In my host I have this

```
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '786M' ); 
define( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '512M' );
```

is this correct, should the `WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT` be higher ?

Answer (score 15):

WordPress tells us:

> the WP_MEMORY_LIMIT option allows you to specify the maximum amount of
>   memory that can be consumed by PHP. This setting may be necessary in
>   the event you receive a message such as "Allowed memory size of xxxxxx
>   bytes exhausted".

Or as the [PHP docs put it](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit)

> [A memory limit] helps prevent poorly written scripts for eating up all available
>   memory on a server.

The [WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Increasing_memory_allocated_to_PHP) also says this about these constants:

> This setting [`WP_MEMORY_LIMIT`] increases PHP Memory only for WordPress, not other
>   applications. By default, WordPress will attempt to increase memory
>   allocated to PHP to 40MB (code is at the beginning of
>   /wp-includes/default-constants.php) for single site and 64MB for
>   multisite, so the setting in wp-config.php should reflect something
>   higher than 40MB or 64MB depending on your setup.

And this about the `WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT` specifically:

> Administration tasks require much [more] memory than [a] usual operation. When in
>   the administration area, the memory can be increased or decreased from
>   the WP_MEMORY_LIMIT by defining WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT.

So `WP_MEMORY_LIMIT` is the limit and `WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT`, if set, will override the former in the admin.

Now when you ask "is this correct", there is no way for us to tell you definitively.

You may want to raise those limits if your site is growing in visitors and or active plugins but if you are not experiencing any issues I would say you are fine for now.

If you choose to up the limits I have outlined the different methods to increase PHP memory in [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/268505/119673). Note the last part about your host potentially limiting this value.

Comment: I note that one of my sites had an issue with 'memory exhausted' during a Postie (plugin) process. Turns out I had WP_MEMORY_LIMIT set to 300M, but no entry for WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT. Since Postie does things at an admin level, I added  WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT to 300M in wp-config, and the memory exhaustion error went away. YMMV.

Answer (score 6):

The `WP_MEMORY_LIMIT` is the default limit set in the front-end, but it can be raised up to `WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT` in wp-admin pages, as well as certain other functions such as image manipulation.

In short, you'll want to have the `WP_MEMORY_LIMIT` set primarily for front-end access, in a way that you won't use up your memory when many concurrent users hit the server.  You'd want `WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT` set higher to allow for admin functions that have heavier requirements, but lower concurrency.