# PHP Warning: include(): Unable to allocate memory for pool

Tags: php, memory

I apologize in advance if this is wrong place to ask my question (mods: please move it to appropriate place)

---

I'm seeing following message in my wordpress logs:

> PHP Warning:  include(): Unable to allocate memory for pool.

and/or

> PHP Warning:  Unknown: Unable to allocate memory for pool. in Unknown
>   on line 0

`php -v`:

```
# php -v
PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Nov  7 2016 11:21:30) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
#
```

`memory_limit` and/or `apc.shm_size` set to `128M`:

```
# grep ^memory_limit ./php.ini
memory_limit = 128M
# grep ^apc.shm_size ./php.d/apc.ini 
apc.shm_size=128M
#
```

---

I've tried setting `memory_limit` to `-1` and/or `512M` for test, yet same results (message above).

Please advise.

Comment: WordPress enforces it's own memory limit on top of the `php.ini`'s limit. It's possible that's the issue. Take a look at [my answer here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/270289/119673) for more info and a potential solution.

Answer (score 1):

Does this topic help (it appears to be referencing the items you are looking at currently) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723316/what-is-causing-unable-to-allocate-memory-for-pool-in-php ?

Comment: No, not really... I've tried to research for this issue prior asking my question and I find few similar to that posts, but that did not help resolve my issue(

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I caused it when tried increasing my memory limits by editing the. htaccess, wpconfig and wpsetup files. Undoing my changes didn't help so I just started over since it was a new setup. I would look at these files as a starting point.