# Out of Memory But theres more than enough

Tags: memory

I know this is asked a lot but mine seems to be unique. I get

```
Out of memory (allocated 2097152) (tried to allocate 4096 bytes)
```

But my phpinfo says I have 380MB in memory_limit.

This is where it gets weird. I only get this error when I try to access different pages but not every time. And the Out of Memory error is the exact same every time.

Comment: You sure you checked the web servers PHP and not the CLI? **Have you spoken to your host about it?**

Comment: WordPress enforces it's own memory limits beyond what PHP is set to. Have you looked into that? I answered related questions [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/270289/119673) and [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/268505/119673). Hope it helps.